# Creating a new library: Pin association to footprints [Kicad 4.0.2]

Tags: footprint, kicad, library

I'm trying to create a library for Lipo battery connectors. I started with the most common connector XT60. I drew the schematic, and then drew the footprints. On Eeschema, I can connect my XT60 to other components without a problem, even I can assign XT60 footprint to it on CvPCB. However, on PCB, no connection is created. 
[image: Here is an example schematic.]

[image: And here is the PCB.]

What exactly do I miss? Apparently it's a very essential part, but I couldn't just extract the necessary source from the internet. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the schematic screenshot, your signals are *not* connected to the battery. The small boxes indicates it. Running the ERC may warn about it.

My guess is that you are trying to draw without using a grid, or you're using something other than the default, mixing different grids.

All the pins in the schematic editor must be aligned to a 100 mil grid, so that they are compatible with each other.

---

Another reason, as the user himself points out in a comment, could be that the pins are actually flipped - you can only connect a signal to one end. This is difficult, if not impossible, to spot in the editor.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this feature of KiCad. Pins are connected now. And another mistake of mine is that, if you look very closely to first picture, you will see the connective side of the pins are reversly placed on XT60. So, it wasn't only an alignment problem; I was trying to wire an _unwireable_ end.

Comment: @MetinOktayYılmaz Ah, I see. That could explain your problem, even _if_ you used the correct grid.